# Export from variable to JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, variables, export

I have created script for storing some data. Function `demo` returns data in JSON format. But I want to create a JSON file for my external project.

```
var demo = function(table) {
  // JSON file 
  var data = [];

  var headers = [];
  headers[0] = 'img';

  // filling headers
  for( var i = 1; i < table.rows[0].cells.length; i++ ) {
      headers.push(table.rows[0].cells[i].children[0].text.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, ''));
  };

  for( var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++ ) {
    var obj = {};

    for( var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++ ) {
      var cells = table.rows[i].cells[j];

      switch (headers[j]) {
        case 'img':
            obj[headers[j]] = cells.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].getAttribute('src');
            break;
        case 'name':
            obj[headers[j]] = cells.childNodes[0].text;
            break;
        default:
            obj[headers[j]] = cells.innerHTML;
            break;
     }
    }
    data.push(obj);
  }
  return data;
}
demo(document.getElementById('the_list'));
```

My question: Is there any possible to export "data" variable to file.txt ?

Comment: I assume you are talking about clientside - why save it to a file and not localStorage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FileSaver.js` -> **https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js**

Here is an example saving a JSON variable :

```
var json = {
    "test" : "qwerty"
}

document.getElementById('save').onclick = function() {
  var textToSave = JSON.stringify(json),
      filename = 'file.txt',
      blob = new Blob([textToSave], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});

  saveAs(blob, filename);
}
```

working fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/sf0o8d4j/1/**

But as mentioned in comment, I really cant see why you should save it as a file locally on the client filesystem rather than using [**`localStorage`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).